# Aerox 155 7k rpm max issue

Tags: rpm, scooter

Good day my Aerox 155 dropped max rpm to 7000 the time I changed my pulley set (rs8 2 angle pulley and drive face). Using my stock pulley the rpm max limit was 8000. I'm using the same fly ball ( dr pulley slider 12 grams). Thank you

Comment: Changing the pulley ratio will affect the power delivery curve...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Since this SE stack is an English only stack, I've removed the portion of your question which was in Filipino, especially since it just repeats what you've added in. Secondly I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you clarify it for us? It appears you are wondering "why" it is doing this, but it is not explicit.

Comment: Yes sir.. good day.. yes im asking for insights regarding the issue of my aerox when it comes to maximum rpm at full throttle after replacing my pulley and driveface. It cannot go beyond 7000 rpm maximum. But it did gain boost in acceleration. What to do with it? Thank you

Comment: Sir PAULSTER2 what do you suggest for me to do withmy aerox to reach 8000 rpm using this current pulley set? Thank you sir

Comment: As a result my top speed dropped by 10%. But it did gain acceleration power